# Handling heavy conditional rendering in react

Tags: javascript, react.js

I have a general question pertaining to a component from one of my apps.  I have a function, `renderConditionals` that is at the core of my UI.  It's incredibly sloppy looking and I am not even sure, from a conventional standpoint, that I am utilizing react correctly with regards to putting functions within the render function.

Basically, I'd love someone to rip this apart and let me know if I'm on the right track or is this sloppy.

`````
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {format, addDays } from "date-fns";
import RouteModal from '../components/RouteModal'
import Arrows from '../components/Arrows'
import '../style/Calendar.css';

export default class Calendar extends Component {
    state = {
        fiveDayView: [new Date(),
        addDays(new Date(), 1),
        addDays(new Date(), 2),
        addDays(new Date(), 3),
        addDays(new Date(), 4)],
        routeId: '',
        show: false,
        colorZero: '',
        colorOne: ''
    }


    grabCityState = (str) => {
    if (str !== null) {
        for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
                if (Number(str[i])){
                    return str.substr(0, str.indexOf(str[i]))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    increaseDays = (e) => {
    let operator;
    if (e.target.id === 'plus'){
        operator = '+'
    } else{
        operator = '-'
    }
        this.setState({
            fiveDayView: [
            addDays(this.state.fiveDayView[0], operator + 1), 
            addDays(this.state.fiveDayView[1], operator + 1), 
            addDays(this.state.fiveDayView[2], operator + 1), 
            addDays(this.state.fiveDayView[3], operator + 1), 
            addDays(this.state.fiveDayView[4], operator + 1)
            ],
        })
    }


    pickupDeliveryMatchDate = () =>{
        let routeInfo = []
            for(let i = 0; i < this.props.apiData.length; i++){
                for(let j = 0; j < this.state.fiveDayView.length; j++) {
                        if (format(this.state.fiveDayView[j], 'YYYY-MM-DD') === this.props.apiData[i].pickup_date) {
                            routeInfo.push(this.props.apiData[i])
                        } 
                }
            }
        return routeInfo
    }
//Need to figure out how to bind this to the function below
    getRouteId = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            routeId: e.target.className.split(" ")[1],
            show: true
        })
}

    hideModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            show: false,
            routeId: '',
        })
    }

    highlightLoad = (e) => {
        let classId = e.target.className
        let colorArr = document.getElementsByClassName(`${classId}`)
        this.setState({
            colorZero: colorArr[0] ? colorArr[0].style.border : false,
            colorOne: colorArr[1] ? colorArr[1].style.border : false
        })
        if (colorArr[0] && colorArr[1]) {
            return [colorArr[0].style.border = 'solid blue 5px', colorArr[1].style.border= 'solid blue 5px']
        } else if (colorArr[0]){
            return colorArr[0].style.border = 'solid blue 5px'
        } else if (colorArr[1]){
            return colorArr[1].style.border = 'solid blue 5px'
        }
    }

    removeHighlight = (e) => {
        let classId = e.target.className
        let colorArr = document.getElementsByClassName(`${classId}`)
        if (colorArr[0] && colorArr[1]) {
            return [colorArr[0].style.border = this.state.colorZero, colorArr[1].style.border = this.state.colorOne]
        } else if (colorArr[0]){
            return colorArr[0].style.border = this.state.colorZero
        } else if (colorArr[1]){
            return colorArr[1].style.border = this.state.colorOne
        }
    }

// set className to ID to do some testing... not a big deal but for learning!
    renderConditionals = (pickupDel, hazmat, sameday, id, delivery_id, delivery_location, j, color) => {
        if (pickupDel === false && hazmat === true && sameday === true) {
            return <span key={j}>
                    <div id="location" onKeyDown={this.getRouteId} key={j} onClick={this.getRouteId}>
                        <p onMouseEnter={this.highlightLoad} onMouseLeave={this.removeHighlight} tabIndex="0" className={['load-clickables', id].join(" ")} style={{backgroundColor: color ? color : this.props.seededColorGenerator(id, delivery_id)}}>{this.grabCityState(delivery_location)}<i style={{color: '#252525'}} className="fas fa-radiation-alt"></i><i style={{color: '#252525'}} className="fas fa-exclamation"></i></p>
                    </div>
                    </span>
        } else if (pickupDel === true && hazmat === true && sameday === true) {
            return <span key={j}>
                    <div id="location" onKeyDown={this.getRouteId} key={j} onClick={this.getRouteId}>
                        <p onMouseEnter={this.highlightLoad} onMouseLeave={this.removeHighlight}  tabIndex="0" className={['load-clickables', id].join(" ")} style={{backgroundColor: '#252525', color: '#fdfd96', border: `solid 5px ${color ? color : this.props.seededColorGenerator(id, delivery_id)}`}}>{this.grabCityState(delivery_location)}<i style={{color: '#fdfd96'}} className="fas fa-radiation-alt"></i><i style={{color: '#fdfd96'}} className="fas fa-exclamation"></i></p>
                    </div>
                    </span>
        } else if (pickupDel === true && hazmat === false && sameday === true) {
            return <span key={j}>
                    <div id="location" onKeyDown={this.getRouteId} key={j} onClick={this.getRouteId}>
                        <p onMouseEnter={this.highlightLoad} onMouseLeave={this.removeHighlight}  tabIndex="0" className={['load-clickables', id].join(" ")} style={{backgroundColor: '#252525', color: '#fdfd96', border: `solid 5px ${color ? color : this.props.seededColorGenerator(id, delivery_id)}`}}>{this.grabCityState(delivery_location)}<i style={{color: '#fdfd96'}} className="fas fa-exclamation"></i></p>
                    </div>
                </span>
        } else if (pickupDel === true && hazmat === true && sameday === false) {
            return <span key={j}>
                    <div id="location" onKeyDown={this.getRouteId} key={j} onClick={this.getRouteId}>
                        <p onMouseEnter={this.highlightLoad} onMouseLeave={this.removeHighlight}  tabIndex="0" className={['load-clickables', id].join(" ")} style={{backgroundColor: '#252525', color: '#fdfd96', border: `solid 5px ${color ? color : this.props.seededColorGenerator(id, delivery_id)}`}}>{this.grabCityState(delivery_location)}<i style={{color: '#fdfd96'}} className="fas fa-radiation-alt"></i></p>
                    </div>
                </span>
        } else if (pickupDel === true && hazmat === false && sameday === false) {
            return <span key={j}>
                    <div id="location" onKeyDown={this.getRouteId} key={j} onClick={this.getRouteId}>
                        <p onMouseEnter={this.highlightLoad} onMouseLeave={this.removeHighlight}  tabIndex="0" className={['load-clickables', id].join(" ")} style={{backgroundColor: '#252525', color: '#fdfd96', border: `solid 5px ${color ? color : this.props.seededColorGenerator(id, delivery_id)}`}}>{this.grabCityState(delivery_location)}</p>
                    </div>
                </span>
        } else if (pickupDel === false && hazmat === false && sameday === true) {
            return <span key={j}>
                        <div id="location" onKeyDown={this.getRouteId} key={j} onClick={this.getRouteId}>
                            <p onMouseEnter={this.highlightLoad} onMouseLeave={this.removeHighlight}  tabIndex="0" className={['load-clickables', id].join(" ")} style={{backgroundColor: color ? color : this.props.seededColorGenerator(id, delivery_id)}}>{this.grabCityState(delivery_location)}<i style={{color: '#252525'}} className="fas fa-exclamation"></i></p>
                        </div>
                </span>
        } else if (pickupDel === false && hazmat === true && sameday === false) {
            return <span key={j}>
                    <div id="location" onKeyDown={this.getRouteId} key={j} onClick={this.getRouteId}>
                        <p onMouseEnter={this.highlightLoad} onMouseLeave={this.removeHighlight}  tabIndex="0" className={['load-clickables', id].join(" ")} style={{backgroundColor: color ? color : this.props.seededColorGenerator(id, delivery_id)}}>{this.grabCityState(delivery_location)}<i style={{color: '#252525'}} className="fas fa-radiation-alt"></i></p>
                    </div>
            </span>
        } else{
            return <span key={j}>
                    <div id="location" onKeyDown={this.getRouteId} key={j} onClick={this.getRouteId}>
                        <p onMouseEnter={this.highlightLoad} onMouseLeave={this.removeHighlight} tabIndex="0"    className={['load-clickables', id].join(" ")} style={{backgroundColor: color ? color : this.props.seededColorGenerator(id, delivery_id)}}>{this.grabCityState(delivery_location)}</p>
                    </div>
                    </span>
        }
    }

    render(){
        console.log('hi')
        return(
        <div className="calendar-container">
            <Arrows {...this.props}{...this.state} grabCityState={this.grabCityState} getCustForm={this.props.getCustForm} getForm={this.props.getForm} increaseDays={this.increaseDays} decreaseDays={this.decreaseDays} />
                    <div className="routeInfo">
                        {this.state.fiveDayView.map(function(days, i){
                    return <div className="days" key={i}>
                                <div>
                                    <div className='month'>
                                        <div id='day-title-one'><h3>{format(days, 'ddd')}</h3></div>
                                        <div id='day-title-two'><p>{format(days, 'D')}</p></div>
                                    </div>
                                    {this.pickupDeliveryMatchDate().map(function(day, j){
                                        if (day.delivery_date === format(days, 'YYYY-MM-DD')){
                                            return this.renderConditionals(day.local_delivery, day.hazmat, day.sameday, day.id, day.delivery_id, day.delivery_location, j, day.color)
                                    } else{
                                        return null
                                    }
                                    }, this)}
                                </div>
                            </div>
            }, this)}
                    </div>
            <div className="title">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div className="routeInfo">
                                    {this.state.fiveDayView.map(function(days, i){
                    return <div className="days" key={i}>
                                <div>
                                    <div className='month'>
                                        <div id='day-title-one'><h3>{format(days, 'ddd')}</h3></div>
                                        <div id='day-title-two'><p>{format(days, 'D')}</p></div>
                                    </div>
                                    {this.pickupDeliveryMatchDate().map(function(day, j){
                                        // need to fgiure out how to tie in your new boolean values to display local cities as #252525
                                        if (day.pickup_date === format(days, 'YYYY-MM-DD')){
                                            return this.renderConditionals(day.local_pickup, day.hazmat, day.sameday, day.id, day.delivery_id, day.pickup_location, j, day.color)
                                    } else{
                                        return null
                                    }
                                    }, this)}
                                </div>
                            </div>
            }, this)}
                    </div>

                <br />
                <br />
            <RouteModal {...this.state} getForm={this.props.getForm} closeModal={this.hideModal} handleChange={this.props.handleChange} {...this.props} show={this.state.show} grabCityState={this.grabCityState} handleClose={this.hideModal} />
        </div>
        )
    }
}
````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waaaay too much duplicate code

For example, in your `renderConditionals` function

```
<span key={j}>
  <div id="location" onKeyDown={this.getRouteId} key={j} onClick={this.getRouteId}>
      <p onMouseEnter={this.highlightLoad} onMouseLeave={this.removeHighlight}  tabIndex="0" className={['load-clickables', id].join(" ")} style={{backgroundColor: color ? color : this.props.seededColorGenerator(id, delivery_id)}}>{this.grabCityState(delivery_location)}<i style={{color: '#252525'}} className="fas fa-exclamation"></i></p>
  </div>
</span>
```

is identical to

```
<span key={j}>
  <div id="location" onKeyDown={this.getRouteId} key={j} onClick={this.getRouteId}>
      <p onMouseEnter={this.highlightLoad} onMouseLeave={this.removeHighlight}  tabIndex="0" className={['load-clickables', id].join(" ")} style={{backgroundColor: color ? color : this.props.seededColorGenerator(id, delivery_id)}}>{this.grabCityState(delivery_location)}<i style={{color: '#252525'}} className="fas fa-radiation-alt"></i></p>
  </div>
</span>
```

Except for the class added to the icon. The easiest way to fix this is to break these items into their own component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Location extends Component {

    render(){
        const { key, id, color, delivery_id, delivery_location, pickupDel, hazmat, sameday,
            handleOnKeyDown, handleOnClick, handleOnMouseEnter, handleonMouseLeave,
            grabCityState, seededColorGenerator
        } = this.props

        return(
            <span key={key}>
              <div id="location" onKeyDown={handleOnKeyDown} key={j} onClick={handleOnClick}>
                  <p onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleonMouseLeave}  
                    tabIndex="0" className={`load-clickables ${id}`} 
                    style={{backgroundColor: color ? color : seededColorGenerator(id, delivery_id)}}>
                        {grabCityState(delivery_location)}
                        <i style={{color: '#252525'}} className={`fas ${ hazmat && 'fa-radiation-alt' } ${ sameday && 'fa-exclamation'}`}></i>
                  </p>
              </div>
            </span>
        )
    }

}
```

I've thrown this location component together. It takes all the common stuff you use in every component, and receives more specific things as generic props. Then you import it into your main calendar component and pass it the props it needs.

Now using it would look something like:

```
renderConditionals = (pickupDel, hazmat, sameday, id, delivery_id, delivery_location, j, color) => 
<Location key={j} id={id} delivery_id={delivery_id} delivery_location={delivery_location} 
    hazmat={hazmat} sameday={sameday} color={color} pickupDel={pickupDel} 
    handleOnKeyDown={this.getRouteId} handleOnClick={this.getRouteId} handleMouseEnter={this.highlightLoad} handleMouseLeave={this.removeHighlight}
    grabCityState={this.grabCityState} seededColorGenerator={this.seededColorGenerator}
/>
```

Now you don't need a big if else statement full of copied code.
Keep in mind I don't 100% understand what things are going on here, I didnt even read your functions, I'm just looking at how things are structured, which is where I think you are the most unfocused. The key takeaway is that if you ever have to copy and paste code in the same project, it can almost definitely be modualized and reused. It might make sense to move functions like `seededColorGenerator` and `grabCityState` into the location component if they are not used elsewhere, instead of passing them as props.

Also, I noticed in your highlighting function, you are using document selectors to change the style of things:

```
let colorArr = document.getElementsByClassName(`${classId}`)`
```

We do not ever use document selectors, or directly query or modify the DOM directly in react. You should always be setting a components class by passing it's style props.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  This is a great help and a good reminder to be more thoughtful about DRYing up my code.  I'll implement this exactly and see how it goes.  I appreciate you taking the time out of your day to dive in.

Comment: You definitely lead me to the right path but the problem is, and it's the main reason why my code was so ugly, is because of the logic I had to implement to have all the correct color options.  One load may be hazmat, while the other is only sameday or vice versa.  There are multiple color combinations I have to account for, so I brute forced it with if/else.

Unfortunately, yours does not cover that aspect of renderConditionals()

Comment: Yes, your requirements for styling seems pretty complicated, alot of logic is unavoidable. However moving location to it's own component is still the right thing to do. You should move the logic that determines it's colors and icon to the location component and calculate the logic there. That way you still avoid duplicating the spans, divs, common props etc.

Comment: I agree with you and I am 100% sticking with your implementation.

By the way, do you think this will noticeably help performance?

Comment: No probably not, it's mostly just for readability and maintanability. If you're having performance issues you're probably rendering too often.